# Ignore SSH host key verification for a subnet

Tags: ssh, openssh

I would like to tell my OpenSSH client(linux) to ignore the host key verification for a given range of IP addresses, is that possible ?

Context : we have this DHCP range we use to build servers before moving them to their production IPs, so I get those SSH warnings regularly and have to delete the offending keys every time...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quite common use case is to put this in your `ssh_config` (`~/.ssh/config`):

```
Match exec "ping -q -c 1 -t 1 %n | grep '192\.168\.'"
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Based on the answer on [openssh-unix-dev](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2015-August/034335.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have some `Host` entries in your ssh config (`~/.ssh/config`) file, which are acting as aliases to actual `HostName` entries, then you'll need to place this block at the very bottom of your config file.

```
Host alpha
  HostName alpha.example.com

Match exec "ping -q -c 1 -t 1 %h | grep '10\.0\.'"
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile none
```

This differs only slightly from @Jakuje's answer. The critical differences are making sure the `Match` entry is the last in the file, and that the `ping` command is using `%h` instead of `%n`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers, here's an example that works for me on **Windows** using `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2`.

```
Match exec "ping -n 1 -w 25 %n | findstr 192\.168\. > nul"
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile none
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want a bit more control and narrow it down a bit.

```
Host 192.168.8.* 10.10.14*.* *.vm.my-net.com
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).